# mysql get distinct row where column has latest date

Tags: mysql

I have a table of entries in a mysql table:

```
script      lastRun     processed
________________________________
scriptA     1663695633  0
scriptB     1663695647  1
scriptA     1663695776  0
scriptB     1663695799  1
scriptC     1663695950  1
scriptA     1663695957  0
scriptB     1663695959  1
```

I am trying to get 1 entry for each script that is the last date run.

the results from the above I am trying to get are:

```
scriptC     1663695950  1
scriptA     1663695957  0
scriptB     1663695959  1
```

I have tried using

```
select distinct script,lastRun,processed from table order by lastRun;
```

but i get all entries.

I have tried using

```
select script,lastRun,processed from table group by script order by lastRun asc;
```

but i dont get the latest run for each.

what query can i use to achieve my goal?

Comment: [Retrieving the last record in each group - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Script, lastRun, processed 
FROM table t1 
WHERE lastRun = (Select MAX(LastRun) FROM table t2 where t2.script = t1.script)
Order by lastrun
```

I usually work with MS SQL, so the syntax for mysql might be slightly different, but essentially you do a subquery to find what the last run time was for that script and only pull that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on MySQL v8, you can combine [common table expression (cte)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) with [ROW_NUMBER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) function as such:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT script, lastRun, processed, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY script ORDER BY lastRun DESC) Rn
     FROM testtable)
SELECT script, lastRun, processed
 FROM cte 
  WHERE Rn=1
ORDER BY lastRun;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/72gOGVTy)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
SELECT script,MAX(lastrun) AS lastrun,processed
FROM scripting
GROUP BY script,processed
ORDER BY lastrun,processed
```

If we run it, It returns:

[image: FER]